# Ray tracing - constructing ray through pixel

Tags: java, pixel, raytracing

I have an assignment to implement ray tracing in Java.
I'm not asking for much, just to have some information on how to construct the rays from the camera through a pixel given its x and y. I've found over the Internet a lot of sources that explain that but in 2D, and I need how to do that in 3D.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you represent the orientation of the camera?

Comment: eye = its position point, direction = its "towards" vector, up-direction = the up direction vector, dist = the distance from the screen. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes. So you know the location of the camera. Do you know how to calculate the position of the center of the screen? The position of a pixel with coordinates x and y on the screen? The ray from the camera to that point?

Comment: The location is given, also the distance from the screen and the direction vector so I also got the center point. The position of the pixel (x,y) on the screen? how do I figure out that? The ray from the camera to that point must be a ray with the location and the direction vector of the vector from the camera to the point we find above, but how would I find that point?

Comment: it seems you almost have all needed information available. What's missing is your FOV and the width to height ratio of your camera. Once you have that it's simple math. Basically using FOV, ratio, location, dir and up create the view pyramid of your camera and with the distance value create your projection plane.

Comment: I have the width of the screen, and the height and width of the canvas, how can I get the height of the screen with those? and the fov?

Comment: the fov and the ratio are more or less arbitrary parameters of your camera. I'd start with a 60 degree FOV and a 3:2 ratio. But might as well use other values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is how to find the coordinates in space of a point on the screen whose position is given by (x,y) in screen coordinates.

I don't know what coordinates system you're using for the screen, so I'll make some educated guesses and you can adjust accordingly.

The center of the screen has known location [X,Y,Z]<sub>center</sub> in space. I'll presume the origin of the screen coordinate system is there. We have a "direction" vector **d** which is normal (perpendicular) to the screen, and an "up" vector **u**. I'll presume that the +y direction on the screen is **u**. We can take the cross-product of these vectors, **r** = **d**x**u**, which I will take to be the +x direction on the screen. So the location of a point on the screen whose screen coordinates are (x, y) will be [X, Y, Z]<sub>center</sub> + x**r** + y**u**, and we're done.

Comment: How come I don't use the screen width, the ratio, the fov and the image resolution in that solution?

Comment: I assumed that (x,y) were in the same units of distance as the 3D space. If they're pixel counts, then before applying this solution you must convert them to distance. What are the *units* of (x,y), screen width, fov and image resolution?

Comment: screenwidth is 2, image resolution? let's say 480X360, and what do you mean by units of x and y?

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is this: you have a camera at a given position (x,y,z) with a given resolution. You have a set of light sources. You have an orientation of the camera (an angle, think of how you'd tilt/rotate your head to look up/down etc...). Now what you want to do is essentially for each camera pixel, "extend" perpendiculars (rays) until they touch geometry. Then you know "what to render" (namely the bit of geometry you've just found). Next up is to determine whether or not the object is shadowed, which you do by "extending" rays towards the light sources until they either touch geometry (your spot is shadowed by the other bit of geometry, for the given the light source) or until they reach the light source (your spot is lit by the given light source).

That's the basics, it gets a lot more difficult when you consider things like reflection, diffusion of light, and so on.